# What is the difference between disjoint union and union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

If $S = A \cup B$, then $S$ is the collection of all points in $A$ and $B$

[image]

What about $S = A \sqcup B$?, I think disjoint union is the same as union, only $A, B$ are disjoint. So the notation is a bit misleading. Because it is not a new operation, but operation where the pair $A,B$ satisfies $A \cap B = \varnothing$.

So given $A \cap B = \varnothing$, $S = A \sqcup B = A \cup B$.

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: In your picture, it looks like $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint.  You can still attempt to write $A \sqcup B$ but it means you somehow alter $A$ and $B$ first to replace them with disjoint sets.  But in some way that the new sets are "the same" as the old ones, for whatever purposes you have.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The notation $A\sqcup B$ (and phrase "disjoint union") has (at least) two different meanings.  The first is the meaning you suggest: a union that happens to be disjoint.  That is, $A\sqcup B$ is identical to $A\cup B$, but you're only allowed to write $A\sqcup B$ if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

The second meaning is that $A\sqcup B$ is a union of sets that look like $A$ and $B$ but have been forced to be disjoint.  There are many ways of defining this precisely; for instance, you could define $A\sqcup B= A\times\{0\}\cup B\times \{1\}$.  This construction can also be described as the [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) of $A$ and $B$ in the category of sets.

(This ambiguity is similar to the ambiguity between "internal" and "external" direct sums; see for instance my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1507179/86856).)

Comment: Well it seems the second meaning is used everywhere even on Wolframalpha, so I went crazy for a while until I decided to self medicate through mathstackexchange

Comment: In my experience, it is not common to actually write the notation $A\sqcup B$ for the first meaning, or to refer to "the disjoint union" (as opposed to just "the union") of $A$ and $B$ as a name for the union.  Rather, you typically say something like "the set $X$ is the disjoint union of its subsets $A$ and $B$" when you already have a name $X$ for the union.