# Ask for some help to understand the notations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, function-and-relation-composition, direct-sum

The following is taken from a text which tries to proves a relation between dimensions of subspaces.

[image]

My first question comes from

> the canonical injections $in_1:M\to M\oplus N$

in line 3 and 4. My understanding of direct sum $M\oplus N$ is that, when we write down this notation, $M$ and $N$ must be independent, i.e., $M\cap N=0$. But since $M$ and $N$ are two arbitrary subspaces as indicated in line 1 an 2, they are not necessarily independent. What does the author mean here? Does $\oplus$ mean something other than direct sum? Furthermore, If we assume $M\oplus N$ denotes direct sum, problems comes out immediately. In line 4, the author wrote

> injections $f:M\cap N\to M\oplus N$

If $M\cap N=0$, then the function $f$ is just the trivial $0\to 0$. So is the following $g$. I believe this is not what the author intended to define.

The second question arises from the third line if Lemma 2.14. I don't really know what that line of symbols and "a short exact sequence" in the subsequent line mean. Does that line of arrows mean something arcane in the circle of math? Of course, the question may due to I don't understand what $f$ means in the first place. I wish I could understand what the author wanted to say, after I have tried hard, so could you please help me understand all these stuff? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What text is this?

Comment: @mizh: "Geometric Methods and Applications: For Computer Science and Engineering", Second edition, by Jean Gallier. Page 46-47.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of direct sums.

Given a subspaces $U_1,U_2$ of a vector space $V$ we can define their *inner sum* $U_1+U_2$ to be the smallest subspace of $V$ containing both $U_1$ and $U_2$. We say this inner sum is *direct*, if $U_1\cap U_2=0$.

Meanwhile there is the *(external) direct sum* of arbitrary vector spaces $U$ and $V$. It is given by their product $U\times V$ with componentwise vector space structure. The notation $U \oplus V$ is there to remind us that the direct sum of vector spaces has some very special properties, which other types of products like the product of sets don’t share.

It may be confusing to have the same symbol $\oplus$ for both the inner and external variant, but this has a reason: Up to isomorphism they are the same. Given two subspaces $U_1,U_2$ of $V$ their sum $U_1+U_2$ is *internally direct* if and only if it is isomorphic to the *external direct sum* $U_1\oplus U_2$.

Now an *exact sequence* is a sequence of vector spaces and homomorphisms
$$...\rightarrow V_1 \overset{\phi_1}{\rightarrow} V_2 \overset{\phi_2}{\rightarrow} V_3 \rightarrow...$$
with the property $\operatorname{Im} \phi_n = \operatorname{ker} \phi_{n+1}$ for all $n$. I cannot go into details here but they are *very* useful. Anyway it is a good exercise in the definitions to check that for subspaces $U_1, U_2$ of $V$ the sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow U_1 \cap U_2 \rightarrow U_1 \oplus U_2 \rightarrow U_1+U_2 \rightarrow 0$$
proposed by your author is exact.

Comment: So you mean $M$ and $N$ do not have to be independent and a product form of direct sum can be defined for $M\oplus N$, which is a set of tuples $(m,n),m\in M,n\in N$, right? If so, what would the canonical injections $in_1$ be? Would it be $in_1(m)=(m,0)$? Do we have to take the component in $N$ to be 0, or any $n\in N$ would do?

Comment: Your definition of $in_1(m)=(m,0)$ is correct and similarly we will have $in_2(n)=(0,n)$. Im afraid I don’t understand your question on the *component in $N$*

Comment: By $component\ in\ N$ I mean the second coordinate of the function value if $in_1$. Sorry for unprofessional wording. Now I have made some progress by understanding that it is not $M\cap N=0$, but their counterparts in product form of direct sum $(m,0)\cap(0,n)=0$ (the zero element in product form of $M\oplus N$, $(0,0)$). I will continue to figure out what exactly $f$ is ...

Comment: No worries! $f$ is defined in your text as the composite of the inclusion $M \intersection N \subseteq M$ with the morphism $in_1: M \rightarrow M\oplus N$. And $g$ is defined similar. So what $f+g$ does is mapping an element $k \in M\cap N$ to $(k,k)\in M \oplus N$.

Comment: I got it. I figured it out and I'm so happy to see that your reply is the same as what I thought. Now I think I have acquired an understanding of all the notations in the text. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Not included in the proof of the text, I put it here just in case one day I forgot. If a short exact sequence $0\to V_1\to V_2\to V_3\to0$ exists, the rank-nullity theorem is $\dim V_2=\dim V_1+\dim V_3$. So, $\dim(U_1 \oplus U_2)=\dim(U_1 \cap U_2)+\dim(U_1+U_2)$. From the isomorphism of $U_1\cong(U_1,0)$ and $U_2\cong(0,U_2)$ in the construction of product form of direct sum, we have $\dim(U_1 \oplus U_2)=\dim U_1+\dim U_2$, which leads to Grassmann relation.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this as an answer because it might be too long for a comment.

You might be confused by what it means to be a direct sum. A direct sum $M \oplus N$ is as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#Construction_for_two_vector_spaces). What you might be referring to is that $M + N = M \oplus N = V$ if and only if $M \cap N = \mathbf{0}$ the zero subspace. See for example [this older MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380056/the-definition-of-direct-sums-and-subspaces). There is often a bit of trouble in the terminology if you're unfamiliar with it, since the direct sum is 'essentially' the direct product (for a finite collection of vector spaces - for an infinite collection, a direct sum is usually imposed by a 'local finiteness' condition, that in any sum there are only finitely many nonzero coefficients).
This definition should answer your first two questions.

As for the second question, a short exact sequence is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence) in Wikipedia.
It is a sequence of five terms, two of which are zero, and it is exact at each component (it's probably helpful to understand what the definition of 'exactness' means - again, look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Definition)).

In the setting of your given lemma, you have injections $f, g: M \cap N \to M \oplus N$ coming from the canonical inclusions $M, N \hookrightarrow M + N$ (can you see why this is the case? This is very straightforward, spelled out in the text, and also follows from our definition above).
Once you've understood this, hopefully the statement should make sense.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out at last. Now I think I have acquired an understanding of all the notations in the text. I'm so sorry that I can accept only one answer, but I'm very thankful for your answer because that adds a lot into my background of algebra. Thank you so much!