# Understanding my mistake when dealing with the direct sum (3 subspaces involved)

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two subspaces $U_1, U_2$, I understand the concept of direct sum

$$ W= U_1 \oplus U_2 \iff W= U_1 + U_2, \quad U_1 \cap U_2 = \{ 0 \}$$

Where $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

I am trying to generalize it for more than $2$ subspaces, say $3$. I thought of the following.

$$ W= U_1 \oplus U_2 \oplus U_3 \iff U_1 \cap U_2 = \{ 0 \}, U_1 \cap U_3 = \{ 0 \}, U_2 \cap U_3 = \{ 0 \}, U_1 + U_2 + U_3 = W $$

It does not seem to have the same structure that for the statement with $k$ subspaces

\begin{align*}
W= U_1 \oplus U_2 \oplus ... \oplus U_k \iff& U_i \cap \left(U_1 + ... + U_{i-1} + U_{i+1} + ... + U_k\right) = \{ 0 \} \\
&U_1 + U_2 + ... + U_k = W
\end{align*}

In particular, the issue lies on the intersection statement. Might you explain why my thought is faulty? I should be able to find a counterexample once I see it :)

**Edit 0**

Let us use the following definition for the direct sum (Axler, page 21)

$U_1 + U_2 + \ ... \ + U_k$ is a direct sum if $x \in U_1 + U_2 + \ ... \ + U_k$ can be written in a unique way as $x = u_1 + u_2 + \ ... \ + u_k$, where $u_i \in U_i$

I think I found a counterexample:

$$U_1 = \{ (x, 0) | x \in \Bbb R\}, \quad U_2 = \{ (y, y) | y \in \Bbb R\}, \quad U_3 = \{ (0, y) | y \in \Bbb R\}$$

These subspaces satisfy $U_1 \cap U_2 = \{ 0 \}, U_1 \cap U_3 = \{ 0 \}, U_2 \cap U_3 = \{ 0 \}, U_1 + U_2 + U_3 = \Bbb R^2$ but not $\Bbb R^2= U_1 \oplus U_2 \oplus U_3$ because we can write, say, the zero vector in (at least) two ways

$$(0, 0) = (1, 0) + (-1, -1) + (0, 1) \quad \text{and} \quad  (0, 0) = (0, 0) + (0, 0) + (0, 0)$$

Do you agree? :)

Comment: counterexample to what?

Comment: Is this from *Linear Algebra Done Right*? Which edition?

Comment: It's unclear to me why Axler's "definition" of a direct sum doesn't introduce the direct sum notation. A more general definition of a direct sum is not an ordinary sum of vector spaces, though it can be isomorphic to a sum of subspaces under some circumstances. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2380056/139123.

Comment: This is a confusion between [internal and external direct sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Internal_and_external_direct_sums). OP refers to internal direct sum, which is a property that some subspaces of a larger vector space can have, while the post linked by @DavidK refers to external direct sum, which is building a new vector space. It is not "more general", it is just a different notion.

Comment: @SolubleFish I think the confusion naturally arises from the overloading of the term "direct sum", though you are correct that the two definitions really refer to different objects and technically one is not "more general". (What I had in mind was merely that it is possible to take the external direct sum of any vector spaces, not just subspaces that satisfy the requirements of an internal direct sum; but of course the result then is not an internal direct sum.)

Comment: @DavidK, third edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that (for three subspaces) $U_1+U_2$ may intersect $U_3$ in a non-zero vector even though $U_1\cap U_3 = \{0\}$ and $U_2\cap U_3 = \{0\}$ - can you find an example of this? If $U_1+U_2$ intersects $U_3$ in a non-zero vector, then the sum $U_1+U_2+U_3$ cannot be a direct sum. (I guess the way to see this depends on the definition of direct sum that you are using - but basically you can represent a vector in the intersection $\left(U_1+U_2\right)\cap U_3$ as a sum of vectors in $U_1$, $U_2$ and $U_3$ in at least two different ways, so uniqueness of representation fails.)

Hope this helps and let me know if you would like further clarifications!

Comment: I think I found a counterexample! Do you agree?

Comment: Hi @JD_PM, yes it works!

Answer (score 2):

This indicates that $U\cap V=\{0\}, U +V = W$ is not the "right" definition (since it does not generalize nicely). Instead, I would take the following as the definition :

> Let $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of subspaces. We say that $\bigoplus_{i\in I} U_i = W$ when, for any $x\in W$, there is a unique family $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ with $x_i \in U_i$, equal to $0$ but for a finite number of them and with  :
> $$\sum_{i\in I}x_i = x$$

Then you could show that the properties you mention are equivalent to this, when $I$ is finite or has two elements.

**Edit 0**

Using this, your counterexample shows that :
$$ W= U_1 \oplus U_2 \oplus U_3 \iff U_1 \cap U_2 = \{ 0 \}, U_1 \cap U_3 = \{ 0 \}, U_2 \cap U_3 = \{ 0 \}, U_1 + U_2 + U_3 = W $$
is not true.

It is easy to show from the definition that direct sum are associative : ie $U_1\oplus U_2\oplus U_3 = W$ iff $U_1$ and $U_2$ are in direct sum and $(U_1\oplus U_2) \oplus U_3 = W$. By induction, you get the right characterization.

Comment: I agree that the definition was not enlightening. Please check edit 0.

Answer (score 1):

@SolubleFish's definition is the right way to generalize the definition of direct sum for more than two subspaces, from this definition it is easy to show that
\begin{align*}
W=U_{1}\oplus U_{2}\oplus \dots\oplus U_{k} \iff& U_{1}\cap U_{2}=\{0\}, \ \left( 
U_{1}+ U_{2}\right) \cap U_{3}=\{0\} \\
&\left( U_{1}+ U_{2}+ U_{3}\right)\cap U_{4}=\{0\} \\
&\vdots \\
&\left( U_{1}+ U_{2}+ U_{3}+\cdots+U_{k-1}\right)\cap U_{k}=\{0\} \\
&U_{1}+ U_{2}+ U_{3}+\cdots+U_{k-1}+U_{k}=W
\end{align*}