# Existence of a “direct union of subsets” operation (matching direct sum of vector subspaces)?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, notation, cardinals

Dimension of vector space and cardinal number of sets have very similar properties :

- Let $U$ be a vector space and $V, W \subseteq U$ two vector subspace, so
  $$
  \dim(V + W) = \dim(V) + \dim(W) - \dim(V \cap W),
  $$
  if $V \cap W = \{0\} \; \Leftrightarrow \; \dim(V \cap W) = 0$, thus
  $$
  \dim(V + W) = \dim(V) + \dim(W),
  $$
  and we write $V \oplus W$, the *direct sum* of $V$ and $W$.
- Let $A$ be an arbitrary set and $B, C \subseteq A$ two subsets, so
  $$
  \mathrm{card}(B \cup C) = \mathrm{card}(B) + \mathrm{card}(C) - \mathrm{card}(B \cap C),
  $$
  if $B \cap C = \emptyset \; \Leftrightarrow \; \mathrm{card}(B \cap C) = 0$, thus
  $$
  \mathrm{card}(B \cup C) = \mathrm{card}(B) + \mathrm{card}(C),
  $$
  and… nothing !

So my question is : Is there an operation “*direct union*” which is to the union of sets what the *direct sum* is to the sum of vector space ?

I found an operation called [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union), but it is not (at all) what I am looking for (disjoint union is indexed union to keep information of the parent set).

Given that write $U = V \oplus W$ is much concise than $(U = V + W) \wedge (V \cap W = \{0\})$, it would be nice to have a notation for “direct union”, *e.g.* ${\,\bigcirc\mathrel{\mspace{-19.5mu}\cup}}$, such that
$$
A = B {\,\bigcirc\mathrel{\mspace{-19.5mu}\cup}} C
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
(A = B \cup C) \wedge (B \cap C = \emptyset).
$$

Comment: Yet, disjoint union is the sum in the category of sets. It is indexes to ensure disjointness. B.t.w. would you be  a fan of Alfred Jarry?

Comment: "Disjoint union" can also refer to an "internal" union which is disjoint; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631396/what-is-the-difference-between-disjoint-union-and-union

Comment: @Bernard I don’t have the fan badge yet ! I wanted to create the question on patamath.stackexchange.com, but it does not exists (yet) !

Comment: @EricWofsey I could use ⊔ for “direct union”, I thought about it, but as you write in response to [What is the difference between disjoint union and union?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631396), this use is not well established, isn’t it ?

Comment: The symbol used in category theory is `\coprod` ($\coprod$).