# How to properly define a set that is a union of pairwise disjoint sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I understand that the term ["disjoint" is ambiguous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140228/why-do-we-say-pairwise-disjoint-rather-than-disjoint), so I want to explicitly define the set $A$ in a clear and, especially, concise way:

- $A = B \cup C \cup D \cup \{e,f\}$
- $B = \{b_{1}, b_{2}, \dots, b_{n}\}$
- $C = \{c_{1}, c_{2}, \dots, c_{m}\}$
- $D = \{d_{1}, d_{2}, \dots, d_{k}\}$

It should be clear that the sets $B, C, D, \{e, f\}$ are pairwise disjoint.
What would be the correct and most concise way to explicitly state this property? Probably $B \cap C \cap D \cap \{e, f\} = \emptyset$?

Comment: No; pairwise disjoint will mean $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $B \cap C= \emptyset$ and...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this is usually done as follows. Instead of $B,C,D,\{e,f\}$ use the notation $A_1 \triangleq B$, $A_2 \triangleq C$, $A_3 \triangleq D$, $A_4 \triangleq \{e,f\}$. Then, we can say $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for all $i,j \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, $i\neq j$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, yes. Are you aware of a "shorter" form of this expression?

Comment: @Andreas Great! Thank you! But would this replace the union definition $A = B \cup C \cup D \cup \{e,f\}$?

Comment: One way: see Eric Wofsey's answer to [What is the difference between disjoint union and union?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1631396/13130) and [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Disjoint_Union_(Set_Theory)#Disjoint_Sets). Another way: see [What is the definition of the $\uplus$ symbol?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/21543/15780) and "Disjoint unions are also sometimes written ..." [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union#Set_theory_definition). FYI, in blackboard lectures I sat in (late 1970s through the 1980s), the version with the dot was almost always used.

Answer (score 1):

For any $A_0,\cdots,A_{n-1}$, usually we say $A_0,\cdots,A_{n-1}$ are *pairwise disjoint* if

\begin{equation}
\text{for any }i\neq j<n\text{ we have }A_i\cap A_j=\varnothing;\qquad(*)
\end{equation}

and we say $A_0,\cdots,A_{n-1}$ are *disjoint* if

\begin{equation}
A_0\cap\cdots\cap A_n=\varnothing.\qquad(\dagger)
\end{equation}

It's not hard to see that $(*)$ implies $(\dagger)$ while the converse doesn't hold. To see the former, without loss of generality suppose $A_0\cap A_1=\varnothing$, then $A_0\cap\cdots\cap A_n=\varnothing$, and to see the latter, setting $A_0=\{0,1\},A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{6\}$ we have $A_0\cap A_1\cap A_2=\varnothing$ but $A_0\cap A_1=\{1\}\neq\varnothing$.