# Epic Monic Factorisation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I want an "algebraic" (something that does not use matrices directly ) proof of the epic monic factorisation property of linear maps . It would be nice if I get to see a proof (with some motivation) of the following problem :

**Let T : V1 → V2 be a linear transformation. Show that there is a vector
space V and linear maps R : V1 → V, S : V → V2 such that R is one to one,
S is onto and T = S ◦ R**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$, and let $R(v) = (v, T(v))$, and let $S(v_1, v_2) = v_2$. Then $R$ is one-to-one, $S$ is onto, and $S(R(v)) = S(v, T(v)) = T(v)$.

Comment: Here , is the sum V1+V2 direct ? If so , please explain a bit more .

Comment: @John yes, $\oplus$ means direct sum, i.e. the set of pairs $(v_1, v_2)$ where $v_1 \in V_1$, $v_2 \in V_2$; the direct sum of two vector spaces is also a vector space.

Comment: Is it true that any vector space V can be written as a direct sum of two vector spaces ? If yes, then can you please refer me to some reading on that part ! Thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: @John why do you ask, that doesn't seem related at all?

Comment: I thought that the fact that we can write V as direct sum of two vector spaces V1 and V2 needed some justification . So , I asked the above question.**Edit (below) -  Oops ! thank you for explaining everything with such patience :P**

Comment: @John we are *defining* $V$ to be the direct sum $V_1 \oplus V_2$. Remember the question asks to show there exists a $V$ with the required properties, we weren't given a $V$ to start with.

Comment: Christopher ,V1 and V2 should have singleton intersection for their sum to be direct ? Please correct me .

Comment: @John there are two similar but not-quite-the-same notions of direct sum, internal direct sum and external direct sum. See this answer for an explanation of the difference https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507156/for-direct-sum-of-modules-can-the-two-modules-be-the-same/1507179#1507179 In the answer I gave, we use the external direct sum.